# Can't GET any more after using custom middleware

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware

I am getting into .NET Core and I am having some problems implementing a custom Middleware. I have a Middleware that is supposed to check whether or not the headers have a field called "user-key". If not, then it returns a 400 ERROR. If it does have it, it should give me the requested GET, but it just gives me a 404 error. When removing the middleware from my startup.cs it works again, but then I can't check if it has a key or not.

**ApiKeyMiddleWare.cs**

```
public class ApiKeyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ApiKeyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("user-key"))
        {
            //Doesn't contain a key!
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400; //Bad request.
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("No API key found.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //Contains key!
            //Check if key is valid here
            //if key isn't valid
            /*
            if(true == false)
            {

                context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid API key found.");
                return;
            }
            */
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

public static class ApiKeyMiddlewareExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder ApplyApiKeyMiddleWare(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();
        return app;
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs - configure method**

```
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {


        app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.ApplyApiKeyMiddleWare();
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });


        //Swagger
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });


    }
```

Let me know if you need something more. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your middleware is fine, but you need to register it using `UseWhen` extension method instead of `MapWhen`.

> `UseWhen`: Conditionally creates a branch in the request pipeline that is rejoined to the main pipeline.
>
> `MapWhen`: Branches the request pipeline based on the result of the given predicate.

In other words, `MapWhen` stops executing the rest of the pipeline when the delegate returns true.

Comment: Yep, it worked. I didn't know UseWhen even existed, thank you! I was very confused.

Comment: @MistaJoe cool, then please [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Accepted, still kind of new to SO, sorry!